# searchable-expression in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

How do I specify multiple XPaths in a searchable-expression in MarkLogic?

I tried the following:

```
let $options :=
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <additional-query>
        <cts:collection-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
            <cts:uri>OncoWatch</cts:uri>
        </cts:collection-query>
    </additional-query>
     <searchable-expression xmlns:es="http://marklogic.com/entity-services"
                           xmlns:wos_dps="http://clarivate.com/schema/wok5.27/public/FullRecord">
        /es:envelope/es:raw/wos_dps:REC/wos_dps:static_data/wos_dps:summary/wos_dps:titles|
        /es:envelope/es:raw/wos_dps:REC/wos_dps:static_data/wos_dps:fullrecord_metadata/wos_dps:abstracts
    </searchable-expression>
    <term>
        <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>whitespace-insensitive</term-option>
        <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
    </term>
    <search-option>unfiltered</search-option>
    <transform-results apply="empty-snippet"/>
</options>
```

I get the following error

> [1.0-ml] XDMP-UNSEARCHABLE: cts:search(fn:collection()/es:envelope/es:raw/wos_dps:REC/wos_dps:static_data/wos_dps:summary/wos_dps:titles | fn:collection()/es:envelope/es:raw/wos_dps:REC/wos_dps:static_data/wos_dps:fullrecord_metadata/wos_dps:abstracts, cts:and-query((cts:word-query("*", ("case-insensitive","punctuation-insensitive","whitespace-insensitive","wildcarded","lang=en"), 1), cts:collection-query("OncoWatch")), ()))[1 to 10] -- Expression is unsearchable

But when I try individual XPaths everything works ...

Answer (score 3):

A searchable expression has to be single expression. You can try putting the conditional portion in the predicate (using `|` instead of "`or`" as the operator), as Elijah suggested.

You can probe for what part of your expression isn't searchable using [`xdmp:query-trace`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:query-trace). Enable it, try to use your expression as an XPath expression, and then look at *ErrorLog.txt* to see if any segment is reported as unsearchable.

Something like this:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
(
  xdmp:query-trace(fn:true()),
  fn:doc()/your/xpath/expr/here,
  xdmp:query-trace(fn:false())
)
```

There's an example of the output here:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/query_meters#id_84776

Answer (score 0):

Please try to write something like:

```
<searchable-expression xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    /(xh:html | CITATION) 
</searchable-expression>
```

Comment: You can also create fields to perform search on specific elements only

Comment: when I do this 
`(/es:envelope/es:raw/wos_dps:REC/wos_dps:static_data/wos_dps:summary/wos_dps:titles|
        /es:envelope/es:raw/wos_dps:REC/wos_dps:static_data/wos_dps:fullrecord_metadata/wos_dps:abstracts)
`
I still get the same error.. how do I tell the search to perform only on a field by default without specifying constrains

Comment: The parentheses have to come after some part of a path. In Navin's example, the only shared path is "/". You could do that (i.e. move the intial slash outside the parens and have two long paths), or something more compact, like this: `/es:envelope/es:raw/wos_dps:REC/wos_dps:static_data/(wos_dps:summary/wos_dps:titles|wos_dps:fullrecord_metadata/wos_dps:abstracts)`

Answer (score 0):

You could add the conditional path in a single XPath expression like the following:

`/es:envelope/es:raw/wos_dps:REC/wos_dps:static_data[wos_dps:summary/wos_dps:titles or wos_dps:fullrecord_metadata/wos_dps:abstracts]`

Comment: okay,,, so searchable expression only takes one xpath then ? if we have multiple xpaths then we do `or` either at the element level or if completely different xpaths then at root level ?